# Transform object from Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, casting

This is my model class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
public class Item{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(name="value")
    private int value;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private int type;

    //getters and setters...
}
```

And when I get the item with id 1 (example) with Hibernate I want to check what type it is and cast it to another class that extends Item. How can I do this?
Example:

```
Item i = (Item) session.get(Item.class, 1);
if(i.getType == 1) {
   i = (Box) i; //This throw me an error
}
```

I also can do a `new Box()`, but then I lose all the data from `Item i`;

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't have much to do with Hibernate.

An instance of Item is not, and will never be, an instance of Box, whether you cast it or not, unless Box extends Item and the Item instance is already an instance of Box. Just like, whatever you might do, a Dog will never be a Car. A Vehicle could be a Car, and if it is, then you can cast the Vehicle to Car without getting an exception.

Implement a Box constructor that takes an Item as argument and wraps it, or copies all its data to attributes of Box.

This is a basic OO question, and frankly, you should probably learn about basics of objects and classes before touching Hibernate, which is quite a complex beast.

Comment: Box is exending Item, i know the other option is create a new Box and pass all the data, but I was thinking i could create a Box depending of the result of the querry

Comment: Car is also extending Vehicle. That doesn't make every Vehicle a Car. Only Car instances can be cast to Car. Not Bike, Truck, or Vehicle instances. Hibernate will only return Box instances if Box is an entity, and thus if Item has an Inheritance annotation, and if the item with ID 1 is indeed a Box and not some other kind of Item. Read on inheritance in Hibernate. But first, read on OO in general.

Answer (score 0):

Good question! You can use InheritanceType.JOINED strategy, and hibernate will do all for you. I suppose `Box` class is inherited from `Item`.  But pay attention on this moment: in branch 4.2.x if you are using complicated database schema with over 100 linked tables (for example) hibernate will generate terrible query with many outer joins. It's solved in branch 4.3.x (I suppose). Look at [link](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6911) We have such problem and can't do anything, because can't migrate to new version of hibernate due to weblogic 12c limitations.